# Reverse proxy with additional logic using CherryPy

Tags: python, proxy, cherrypy

Is it possible to run a CherryPy application as a reverse proxy, to intercept ALL requests and rewrite them depending on the URL and other logic?

My aims:

- intercept all requests and perform home-rolled authentication
- rewrite the requests to different services (perhaps on different ports) depending on the URL
- return the result

All the examples I find refer to putting CherryPy behind a reverse proxy like Apache.

I would imagine there's a hook function that can be overridden

I've looked the [CherryProxy](http://www.decalage.info/python/cherryproxy) package, but the documentation is sparse, and it looks like it's just using CherryPy hooks anyway.

Comment: See if my previous answer is of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19921085/1914052

Comment: It did help, but doesn't solve the part where I need to rewrite to another service. Perhaps my question needs to be phrased better.

Comment: If logic is simple, use a proxy as you mentioned. Otherwise you should look into async frameworks and definitely not CherryPy.

Comment: i would like to capture the cherrypy request and proxy it to another service.